# Laravel 5.2 multiple table authentication and middleware together not working properly

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am using laravel 5.2 multiple table(user, admin) auth feature for using two tables one for users and another for admins. Everything is working properly except middleware functionalities . Default 'auth'(Authenticate.php) is not working and I make a custom one 'auth.super_admin'(SuperAdminMiddleware.php) for checking user is whether admin and result is same . Here is my auth.php file

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins'
        ]
    ],
```

Here is Authenicate middleware and SuperAdminMiddleware method :

```
Authenticate.php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
         if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

SuperAdminMiddleware.php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if(\Auth::guard('admins')->check())
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

So when i am using 'auth' in a constructor of a controller it does not works and corresponding method is invoked . What wrong I am doing or missing ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something about the picture you're painting, but I don't believe you can define the handle method twice in the same file.

Comment: No one method is in Authenticate.php middlware and other is in SuperAdminMiddleware.php file . @JeremyAnderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have solved the problem . Here is solution

```
Authenticate.php


public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authenticate Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This middleware is for checking whether user is from user table .
    | and authenticated.
    |
    */
        if (!Auth::user()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }else
        {
            return $next($request);

        }
    }
```

SuperAdminMiddleware.php

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authenticate Middleware(Super Admin check)
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This middleware is for checking whether user is from admin table 
    | and super_admin .
    |
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {


        if (\Auth::guard('admins')->user()) {
            if(\Auth::guard('admins')->user()->type == 'super_admin')
                return $next($request);

            return redirect('/');
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```